# VMware time sync problem - ubuntu (guest) on windows 7 (host)

Tags: time, synchronization, vmware

I am running Ubuntu as a guest OS using VMware player on my Windows 7 machine. The problem I have is syncing the clock in the Ubuntu machine. This happens only when I close the VMware player and open the suspended session. For example if I close my VMware player running Ubuntu at 4:15 PM and then restore it at 5:45 PM, it still shows 4:15 PM. (This does not happen when I shutdown the Ubuntu OS.)

I searched the [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276965/how-to-keep-a-vmware-vms-clock-in-sync) forum and found that by setting

```
tools.syncTime = true 
tools.syncTime.period = 60
```

should help resolve the problem. But this change did not work for me. Any pointers to resolve this issue would be helpful.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I had the same clock sync issue. Installing VMware tools solves the problem.

But if it doesn't help, you can do it manually by calling `sudo ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com` every time you open the suspended session.

Comment: after you install the tools, make sure you enable timesync by running: `vmware-toolbox-cmd  timesync enable` in the terminal. It's found in /usr/bin.