# Github shows wrong time of commits

Tags: git, github

This problem happens all the time and it drives me crazy. I will add, commit and push a file up to github and it will display the wrong time as to when it was committed. Sometimes it will show that the commit happened a few **days** prior to when it actually was just added, committed and pushed (which rules out a simple timezone discrepancy). Even when I initialize a brand new repository and commit a file immediately afterward, it will say that it happened 2 days ago.

If anyone knows of an article or previously answered question that deals with this issue, I would greatly appreciate you pointing it out to me.

Comment: Are you only doing simple commits, or are you doing rebasing, cherry-picking, or stuff like that?

Comment: @RobinGreen, I'm just doing simple commits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Double-check your system clock. GitHub's UI is showing the timestamp from the commits themselves, which git reads from the system when you make the commit.

A quick way to check this is to make a new commit, then do `git log` and check that the time and date match the settings on your system.

Comment: You're right. It appears that it's my VM that's messed up. How can I fix it?

Comment: Manually? Depends on the OS. Your VM hosting software might have a setting for this, though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276965/how-to-keep-a-vmware-vms-clock-in-sync

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same issue while using WSL, these two commands fixed it for me.

First ensure **ntpdate** is installed:

`sudo apt install ntpdate`

Then run:

`sudo ntpdate pool.ntp.org`

You can read related questions/threads on this issue [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81293/what-is-the-command-to-update-time-and-date-from-internet?newreg=f8877abaf4b64957a1b1f1d9fc0028aa) and [here](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4245).

Answer (score 1):

This is how I reset the time on my scenario to fix this issue.

I use Ubuntu on WSL. I'm not sure why my time was off, but I shut down WSL, and ubuntu restarted(when I opened it) with the *correct* time from PC's system time.

Use the following command in Windows PowerShell to shut down WSL :

**wsl --shutdown**

After restarting Ubuntu use this command in Ubuntu to check the time:

**date**

Comment: This worked for me. In case of wsl, this is the simplest technique.